# multi-styled / virtual host web application with Play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.3 project, and am looking to try build a webapp that has different views based on a certain criteria. I'm about to start playing around with it, but thought I'd put a question out there as to how I could go about it, while I start investigating on my side.

The look and feel of the site will change based on hostname, with a base site that is used by default. Most of the underlying functionality (controllers and model) will stay the same. So for example, www.mysite.com/index will render an "index" template, with all referenced assets. However newsite1.mysite.com/index will load a different template if it exists, and different assets (stylesheets) if they exist. If there isn't a custom template / view, then it uses the default.

I'm thinking about using a pathing inside a project, and possibly some sort of inheritence where 1 view uses another view as a base, but overrides some sections, or Assets.at will look for a virtualhost-specific asset first.

Is there something in the play framework that I could use to do this? Has anyone else done something similar, and how did you do it?